# Reference an element within an element found by index

Tags: jquery, css

I have an unordered list that contains multiple elements within each list item. I need to reference the checkbox under one of the li elements found by index:

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 600px; overflow: hidden auto;">
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:514">Item 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:515">Item 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:516">Item 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:517">Item 4</label></li>
    <li>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:525">Item 5</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can get the li element at index 3 with:

```
$('ul li').eq(3)
```

...but how to I reference the specific input[type=checkbox] under the li at index 3?

Comment: um, select the input? `...eq(3).find("input")`

Comment: checkbox inside of an anchor tag? I do not think that is valid HTML.

Comment: That's actually autogenerated code from the bootstrap-multiselect control. but thanks for the selector, that works. I'll remove the anchor tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your HTML code is a little bit weird as stated in the comments. If you want to get a specific input, you can do it that way :

**Code snippet**

```js
var checkboxValue = $('ul li').eq(3).find("input[type='checkbox']").val();
console.log(checkboxValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 600px; overflow: hidden auto;">
<li>
    <a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:514">Item 1</label>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:515">Item 2</label>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:516">Item 3</label>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:517">Item 4</label>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="object:525">Item 5</label>
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I used the find method (here : https://api.jquery.com/find/).